# Start with two monitors not working

Tags: 20.04, amdgpu

I have two monitors connected display port. My graphics card is Radeon XT 5500.

During system startup I see artefacts and black screen. If I use only one monitor (one port display port) the system works perfectly (and I can join second monitor - two monitor working). Each time I must turn on the system with only one monitor:

[image: Photo of artefacts]

Answer (score 0):

Resolving:

Added this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.dpm=0"
```

to: /etc/default/grub